# MySQL result array into session variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple MySQL query, I've checked the query in phpmyadmin and it returns 2 results.

I would like to put the result straight into a session variable which should be fairly easy, i have the code below and i only get the first result.

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_data);

 $_SESSION['data'] = $row;
```

In my head, this should put the result set into the $row variable, but it doesn't contain all the data. Would i need to wrap it in a loop?

Comment: Yes you have to loop through all the rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call mysql_fetch_assoc it returns one row.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_data)) {
    $_SESSION['data'][] = $row;  
}
```